# Exposing REST api of Hive Query using JDBC and Spark Java

Tags: java, rest, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I have use Spark Java library for exposing REST API. 
I have used JDBC driver for HIVE to query tables. I have established connection to Hive inside main method, after connection is established i have created POST method.
Inside POST method with query as parameter, i have fired query using above mentioned connection.
Everything works fine.
But when i call this POST url simultaneously from 3 machine, result is returned to last called machine only, other 2 will not result at all.
Please help how to use JDBC hive with simultaneous query.

Below is the code in main function,

```
try {
Class.forName(driverName);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
System.exit(1);
}
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
"jdbc:hive2://<ip address>:10000/default", "", "");
stmt = con.createStatement();
get("/query/:querystring", (req,res) -> executeQuery(req));
```

Below is the POST method,

```
public static String executeQuery(Request req) {
try {
String sql = req.params("querystring");
System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

JSONArray json = new JSONArray();

ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
while (rs.next()) {
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

for (int i = 1; i < numColumns + 1; i++) {
String column_name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);

if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.ARRAY) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getArray(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.BIGINT) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getLong(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.REAL) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getFloat(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getBoolean(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.BLOB) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getBlob(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.DOUBLE) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getDouble(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.FLOAT) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getDouble(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.INTEGER) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getNString(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.VARCHAR) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getString(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.CHAR) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getString(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.NCHAR) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getNString(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.LONGNVARCHAR) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getNString(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.LONGVARCHAR) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getString(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.TINYINT) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getByte(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.SMALLINT) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getShort(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.DATE) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getDate(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.TIME) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getTime(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getTimestamp(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.BINARY) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getBytes(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.VARBINARY) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getBytes(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.LONGVARBINARY) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getBinaryStream(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.BIT) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getBoolean(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.CLOB) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getClob(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.NUMERIC) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getBigDecimal(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.DECIMAL) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getBigDecimal(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.DATALINK) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getURL(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.REF) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getRef(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.STRUCT) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getObject(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.DISTINCT) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getObject(column_name));
} else if (rsmd.getColumnType(i) == java.sql.Types.JAVA_OBJECT) {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getObject(column_name));
} else {
obj.put(column_name, rs.getString(i));
}
}

json.put(obj);
}
return (json.toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO: handle exception
return null;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also post your code.

Comment: @DimaSan i have added code. Please help